# Varchar variable is not working in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, variables, sql-server-2008-r2

Why does this work...

```
DECLARE @MyInt int = 12345;
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyId = @MyInt; --Returns 1 row
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyId = 12345;  --Returns 1 row
```

but this doesn't?

```
DECLARE @MyVarchar varchar = 'ABCDEF';
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyId = @MyVarchar; --Returns 0 rows
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyId = 'ABCDEF';   --Returns 1 row
```

SQL Server version is 10.50.1746

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because when you `declare`, default `varchar` length is `1`. So `@MyVarchar` ends up being `'A'`.

This is different to `cast(something as varchar)`, where [default length is `30`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks).

The right thing is

```
DECLARE @MyVarchar varchar(10) = 'ABCDEF';
```

where `10` is the length of the column in the table.

Comment: Here I was trying to figure out why this isn't working only to realise the code I inherited had declared the variable with a length of 13 when the input string's length is 15! Thanks @GSerg