# Why does condition @parameter like (condition) not return results, while replacing the parameter with a literal does?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I was trying this in mssql2008:

```
declare @test nvarchar

set @test = '12345'

select 'true' where @test like '%3%' -- no results, condition fails

select 'true' where '12345' like '%3%' -- returns true, condition passes
```

Can someone please explain to me why the first select statement does not return any result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Varchar variable is not working in WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580076/varchar-variable-is-not-working-in-where-clause)

Comment: sorry i had no idea, this thing stumped me for a long time so i posted here hoping someone can help me

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand good read, thanks

Comment: Also, if it's nvarchar, you should say `N'12345'` and not `'12345'`. This is to protect yourself from losing data when the string does contain Unicode characters. And if the string will never contain Unicode characters, then stop using nvarchar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
declare @test nvarchar
```

to

```
declare @test nvarchar(10)
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21861)

So to answer your question, from [nchar and nvarchar (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the
>   CAST function, the default length is 30.

Comment: or even `nvarchar(5)` :)

Comment: thank you very much. u are good. I spent 1 hour staring at this and could not figure out why

Answer (score 0):

This happends because @test nvarchar is initialised with a size of 1 i.e. it only contains '1' from the your set statement.

If you change the declare statement to @test nvarchar(5), it'll work.