# Returning a True or False value in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, vb6, ssms

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio where I can find any invoices in a table belonging to a certain Vendor with a certain status. For example I have Vendor 123456 from my VB application and I want to find if they have any invoices in my InvoiceTable where the status = B and return either a true or false value. This is what I have been trying so far:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckStatus] 

@VendorNumber  char    
AS
BEGIN

Select distinct
CASE WHEN OrderStatus = 'B' and VendorNumber = @VendorNumber then 'true' else 'False' END as Status
from InvoiceTable

END
```

Right now it always returns a singular "False" value, no matter if orderstatus = B and vendornumber = @vendornumber or not.

I'm not sure if this is possible or I'm even on the right page

Comment: Your query builds a list of 'true' or 'false' for all records in the table and then `distinct`s it to `'true','false'`. Apparently 'false' happens to be on the first row and your app never reads the second row.

Comment: I would move your case clauses into a where clause, select count from that and if your result > 0, then you know you have invoices. Your distinct is probably always going to return 2 rows: 'True' and 'False' and it probably just so happens that false is first

Comment: @Madafu Right now it only returns a bunch of rows,one for each invoice , but they are always all false. That is why I have the distinct, hoping it would return a 'True' and 'False' At least if It returned True and False I would know it is hitting all of the different invoices but it is not.

Comment: @MikeDavis My psychic powers tell me your `= @VendorNumber` is never true because you [declared it as `char`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8580115/11683).

Comment: @GSerg I declared it the same datatype as it is in my table

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have something like `char(50)` in the table @MikeDavis.

Comment: Isn't what all the datatypes are supposed to be @GSerg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
    FROM InvoiceTable
    WHERE OrderStatus = 'B' and VendorNumber = @VendorNumber
    ) 
  SELECT 'True'
ELSE
  SELECT 'False'
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find if they have any invoices in my InvoiceTable where the
>   status = B and return either a true or false value

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM InvoiceTable
    WHERE OrderStatus = 'B' and VendorNumber = @VendorNumber
    ) > 0
  SELECT 'True'
ELSE
  SELECT 'False'
```

Comment: Please never use `count` where you only need [exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336%28v=sql.120%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Result varchar(10)

IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
        FROM InvoiceTable
        WHERE OrderStatus = 'B' and VendorNumber = @VendorNumber
        ) 
BEGIN
      SET @Result = 'True'
END
ELSE BEGIN
      SET @Result = 'False'
END

RETURN @Result
```

Note - You can use bit instead of returning 'True' or 'False'