# Assigning int value to a varchar variable without specifying length returns * why?

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @ID VARCHAR
PRINT @ID
SELECT @ID=CAST(10 AS VARCHAR)
PRINT @ID
SELECT @ID
```

returns *

why ?

Comment: This is [well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#truncating-and-rounding-results) [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) (two links)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've never seen the `*`, and the OP's code in particular yields `1` for me like I would expect. I can see the `*` is documented, but how to make it appear?

Comment: cast(10 as varchar(2))  or varchar(max) or else value in parentheses

Comment: @mrR That is [not the place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8580115/11683) to put the `(2)`.

Comment: you're right     DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(2)  or better VARCHAR(10)

Answer (score 0):

In varchar(n/max) when n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. That's why returning *(only single value).