# SQL SERVER: Selecting numerals following Some Characters

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to select some numerals from a long string, which are following some characters that is `:RCT`. So far I have managed to write this script;

```
  DECLARE @rct varchar(MAX)
  SET @rct = 'Reallocation of Identified Receiptsv6055161LIVERPOOL SCHOOL OF TROPICAL MEDICINE (LSTM) LONDON(GROUPA8):RCT1122489'

  SELECT SUBSTRING(@rct, CHARINDEX(':RCT', @rct), LEN(@rct)) as RCT
```

Unfortunately, it returns an empty result. The result I expect is;

```
  RCT
--------
1122489
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Varchar variable is not working in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580076/varchar-variable-is-not-working-in-where-clause)

Comment: Agreed it has returned some result but I still need to select the numerals it now returns `:RCT1122489`

Comment: [Declaring a VARCHAR without a length specification](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)... this is what it leads to.

Comment: @TT Necessary changes have been done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more efficient way to return end-index of ':RCT' from the parent string.

But the following does the job for you:

```
 DECLARE @rct varchar(MAX)
 SET @rct = 'Reallocation of Identified Receiptsv6055161LIVERPOOL SCHOOL OF TROPICAL MEDICINE (LSTM) LONDON(GROUPA8):RCT1122489'

 SELECT SUBSTRING(@rct, CHARINDEX(':RCT', @rct)+LEN(':RCT'), LEN(@rct)) as RCT
```