# How to concatenate 2 VARCHAR variables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to concatenate 2 VARCHAR variables in SQL Server `@FirstName`, `@LastName` into a 3rd VARCHAR variable: `@FullName`.

I tried to approaches below:

```sql
DECLARE @FirstName VARCHAR = 'Michelle'
DECLARE @LastName VARCHAR = 'Ma Belle'
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR = @FirstName + @LastName

PRINT @FullName
```

=> `M`

```sql
DECLARE @FirstName VARCHAR = 'Michelle'
DECLARE @LastName VARCHAR = 'Ma Belle'
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR = CONCAT(@FirstName, @LastName)

PRINT @FullName
```

=> `'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

But none of them gives what I want to achieve.

Comment: `VARCHAR`  == `VARCHAR(1)`

Comment: This is what comes of lazy coding habits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Varchar variable is not working in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580076/varchar-variable-is-not-working-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the size of varchar columns coz if you omit to mention the size with varchar, by default it takes the size as only 1. Please update your code to -

```
DECLARE @FirstName VARCHAR(20) = 'Michelle'
DECLARE @LastName VARCHAR(20) = 'Ma Belle'
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(40) = @FirstName + @LastName

PRINT @FullName
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a size to your VARCHAR fields.

```
DECLARE @FirstName VARCHAR(50) = 'Michelle'
DECLARE @LastName VARCHAR(50) = 'Ma Belle'
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(110) = @FirstName + @LastName

PRINT @FullName
```

Result: MichelleMa Belle

I suggest you add a space

```
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(110) = @FirstName + ' ' + @LastName
```

Result:   Michelle Ma Belle