# (SQL Server 2017) I get error Msg 8152 and I don't know why

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have no idea why, but I am getting the error Msg 8152 (in SQL Server 2017) after trying to insert something like

```
INSERT INTO Users (usr_name, usr_pwd, usr_thing1, usr_thing2)
VALUES ('ticko', 'kgrhjwekr3h4', 1, '34798563');
```

into the table

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    usr_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(0, 1),
    usr_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    usr_pwd VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    usr_thing1 INT NOT NULL,
    usr_thing2 VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    usr_group INT,
    usr_status VARCHAR DEFAULT 'ACTIVE',
    usr_created DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    FOREIGN KEY (usr_group)
        REFERENCES Groups(grp_reqid)
);
```

The output I get is

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You realise all your `varchar` columns have [length of 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8580076/11683)?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Since you **haven't** specified any length, your `VARCHAR` columns are **exactly ONE character** long - so the string you're trying to insert is **too long** and thus this error occurs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a length for your `VARCHAR` columns

For example

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    usr_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(0, 1),
    usr_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    usr_pwd VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    usr_thing1 INT NOT NULL,
    usr_thing2 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    usr_group INT,
    usr_status VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'ACTIVE',
    usr_created DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    FOREIGN KEY (usr_group)
        REFERENCES Groups(grp_reqid)
);
```

Comment: . . You don't *need to* define a length (although it is a best practice).  Obviously, SQL  Server accepts the table definition with no length specified.  The issue is that the default length varies by context and in this context is "1", which is not large enough.  I WISH SQL Server required the length but it does not.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I could've sworn I had already tried doing that. Seems like I hadn't, lol.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have not given how may length you want to insert in varchar and int.
First associate the length to it then run it, it will not show any errors.